# Angular2 RxJS - split collection of urls to fetch into smaller chunks

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I use Angular2.4.8. I have collection of url to fetch (dozens of them). Currently I fetch them all at once but it often happens that server can't handle so many requests simultaneously. Current code:

```
let collectionsRequests = Array.from(collectionsUrls, url => this.http.get(url));
Observable.forkJoin(collectionsRequests).subscribe((collectionResponses: Response[]) => {
    collectionResponses.forEach(response => {
        // parse responses
    });
});
```

where `collectionsUrls` is array of strings (urls) to fetch.

I'd like to divide those requests to packs with 10 requests and when one pack is finished then next pack start until end of array.

I tried to use `bufferCount` and `concatMap` but with no success. Although probably this is a good direction. How should it look like?

Comment: The first approach is more sufficient if you want to fetch a large number of responses.

Comment: @RomanC I assume you are talking about `bufferCount` and `concatMap`. I know this is a good direction but I don't know how to handle this. I need little advice.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the parameter `concurrent` of `mergeMap` operator. Documentation and example [here](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html).

The `concurrent` parameter enables you to dictate how many requests you want to be executing at any given time. if you use `concurrent` set to 10, then when the 10th call will have been emitted, your operator will stall, and wait for one slot to be free, before processing the next call.

Then you can congregate all the results for example with the `toArray` operator.

```
function identity(x) {return x}
Rx.Observable.from(collectionsUrls)
    .mergeMap(url => this.http.get(url), identity, 10).toArray()
    .subscribe((collectionResponses: Response[]) => {
        collectionResponses.forEach(response => {
            // parse response
        });
});
```

This is untested, so let me know if it works.

Comment: Cannot find name 'mergeMap'. In the examples `mergeMap` is applied to an observable.

Comment: hopefully that conforms to the `mergeMap` signature now

Comment: `collectionsRequests` is an array and array does not have `mergeMap`

Comment: Still does not work. In subscriber the array contains objects of type `Observable`.